# Arrange data in MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a users table and a categories table which already contain data,
I also have a third table which called `user_category` which has three `columns(id,user_id,category_id)`.

When the user first register he must choose a category or more than one from a dropdown. I want to insert the id of the user to `user_id` columns and the id of each category to the `category_id` so if the user choose more than one category he will have more than one record in the `user_category` table.

Comment: Nice requirement ... what have you tried BTW?

Comment: i have tried to select the id from category table where category_name = $_post['category'] and then insert it to category_id in the common table and it works in case of the user choose one category but when he choose many i will have an array which i don't know how to insert it to the table,

Comment: the other problem is how to select the user because it is not in the database yet...

Comment: Do you have a question? Note that the id column in your 3rd table is redundant.

Comment: i want to ask how to create a query to accomplish that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This

`SELECT user_id FROM users
ORDER BY user_id DESC
LIMIT 1`

This will give you the last user_id which has inserted Now by using this user id you can insert the category_id by for each loop or for loop

Comment: i used  mysqli_insert_id in php to get the last id but thank you for your help i didn't know that i need to use foreach loop